# How to change the contents of multiple span tags in python

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get every span named "count" and change the text to a ", "

```
<div class="tag-container">
  Tags:
  <span class="tags">
   <a class="tag tag-number" href="/tag/tagname/">
    <span class="name">
     tag
    </span>
    <span class="count">
     count
    </span>
   </a>
   <a class="tag tag-number2" href="/tag/tagname2/">
    <span class="name">
     tag2
    </span>
    <span class="count">
     count2
    </span>
   </a>
   <a class="tag tag-number3" href="/tag/tagname3/">
    <span class="name">
     tag3
    </span>
    <span class="count">
     count3
    </span>
   </a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Here is the code I have tried, it works for the first span, but won't change any of the following spans

```
metadata = soup.find("section", { "id":"tags" })
count = metadata.find_all("span", class_="count")
for count in metadata:
    count = metadata.find_next("span", class_="count").get_text
    if count is ", " :
        continue
    else:
        count = metadata.find_next("span", class_="count").string.replace_with(", ") 
metadata = soup.find("section", { "id":"tags" })        
print(metadata.text)
```

what I am trying to get is

```
Tags:
tag, tag2, tag3,
```

here is the output that I get

```
Tags:
tag, tag2count2tag3count3
```

I am still pretty new to python, so I'm sure there is a simpler solution that I can't figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines:

```
for t in metadata.select('span.count'):
    t.string.replace_with(',')
soup.text.replace('\n','').replace('  ','')
```

Output:

```
'Tags: tag, tag2, tag3,'
```

Comment: @HimuraXIII If we are done, can you accept the answer, please?